# property rootNode in struts2-jquery-tree-plugin doesn't run

Tags: json, jquery-plugins, struts2, tree

I'm testing struts2 **jquery-grid-tree plugin** but when I render a tree whose info come from an action in JSON format, I have some troubles.

As I want more info from my action for another purposes, my action return not only tree nodes info, but other regarding as operation ACK, and so on...

That's an example of my action result:

```
{"JSON":"success", "nodes":[{id":"001", "children":null,"data":{"title":"First element "}, "icon" : null,....
```

So in my tree tag I try to tell the plugin to retrieve info from "nodes" property inside the action's response using "rootNode" property, in this way:

```
 <sjt:tree       
  href="%{testJSONTreeAction}"
  id="testTreeWithCheckbox" 
  rootNode="nodes"
  childCollectionProperty="children"
  ....
```

but it doesn't work.

**The only way it runs fine** is if my response returns just the info about my tree as follows:

```
[{"attr":{"id":"001"},"children":null,"data":{"title":"First element"}...
```

I means, just the node information.

Of course I could manage formatting the response as above, but I wonder what is this attribute for. Other tags like grid tags has an attribute for this (gridModel) and works fine, but I can't find it in tree tags docs.

I've seen some related bugs like [here](http://struts2-jquery-plugin.109969.n3.nabble.com/Issue-576-in-struts2-jquery-Bug-TreeNode-case-quot-Tree-with-Types-quot-does-not-work-when-quot-roott-td3124891.html) but they are regarding old versions and I'm trying **the last release of the plugin, 3.5.1.**

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Is this a typo "nodes"?

Comment: hi @RomanC . What do you mean? I am not using types for nodes. "nodes" is just the JSON property I want to use to tell the tree where the information  about nodes is.